# Default value in constructor parameter based on template type

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have a class as follows

```
template <int len, bool is_internal=false>
class MyClass
{
    int var;
    char* buffer;

    MyClass(int v, char* buff)
    {/* some logic that initializes buffer */}
};
```

What i want is that when `in_internal` is true, the class constructor to not require the value of buffer in arguments, but make sure that is provided when `is_internal` is false.

I can do it with `is_internal` being a class member, but it creates a lot of code duplication in constructors, and i think there must be a cleaner way of doing this using templates or constexpr, and have things in compile time managed by the compiler. I also want the destructor to unallocate the buffer if `is_internal` is true.

Edit -
this is something i wish for but in a neat way to be taken care of in compile time-

```
MyClass(int v, char* buff = nullptr)
{
    if(is_internal == true)
      assert(buff==nullptr);
    else
      assert(buff != nullptr);
    // rest of the common code.
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to C++20? You could write `MyClass(int v, char* buff) requires !is_internal` and `MyClass(int v) requires is_internal`.

Comment: @NathanPierson's solution works without c++20, but requires some not so pretty SFINAE `std::enable_if` trickery.

Comment: I donot want to create two constructors, since it causes lot of code duplication. I have other functions dependent on this boolean as well. That is the reason im trying to use templates in the first place.

Comment: You can't give one function two signatures. You might be able to get away with having one constructor delegate to another... But then again, you might not. It depends a lot on what `MyClass` is doing and whether or not `MyClass<x, true>` really has that much in common with `MyClass<x, false>`.

Comment: Since the class code will be expanded by the compiler, separately for is_internal being true/false. I want one of the constructors for false case and one for true case.

Comment: @joergbrech Well there is also `if constexpr` which would not be too bad here.
`if constexpr(is_internal) { } else {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if constexpr`

```
MyClass(int v, char* buff = nullptr)
{
    if constexpr(is_internal)
    {
      assert(buff==nullptr);
    }
    else
    {
      assert(buff != nullptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understood the question, that if `is_internal` is there, there should be a default argument (which can be overwritten), while if it's false, there is no default argument.

Comment: yes @joergbrech, slight correction. is_internal = true means that argument is not required.

Comment: And that if the template argument is used by client code then the value is false. And the code will compile to `assert(buff==nullptr)`

Comment: I meant "template argument is NOT used"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create 2 complete constructors. You can use delegate constructor, like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int len, bool is_internal=false>
class MyClass
{
    int var;
    char* buffer;

public:
    MyClass(int v, char* buff)
    {/* some logic that initializes buffer */}

    template<bool ii = is_internal>
    MyClass(std::enable_if_t<ii, int> v) : MyClass(v, nullptr) {}
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<10> a(5, nullptr);
    MyClass<20, true> b(8);
    //MyClass<30> c(9); // Error
}
```